# Handling accented characters

Tags: php, android, json

I store place names from all over the world (for example Râşnov) which is stored in a database correctly, and when sent to/from php it is shown/saved correctly. And when sent to android it shown correctly, but when I try to send any accented characters (and some others) to the database via php from android, it fails, and stops reading the json at the first bad character.

Android:

```
final HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
final HttpPost poster = new HttpPost(Constants.COMMAND_URL);    
poster.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
final String jsonString = cmd.getJSON().toString();    
poster.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonString));    
final HttpResponse response = client.execute(poster);
```

php:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8', true,200);
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = json_decode($data, true);
```

Example JSON:

```
{"Params":{"PageIndex":0,"PageSize":20,"SearchTerm":"râs"},"Request":"Search","SessionID":"3EF90227"}
```

When I get JSON from the server it shows as

```
{"Result":1,"Results":[{"PlaceName":"R\u00e2\u0219nov Citadel","Country":"Romania","OnlineID":"142","Location":"R\u00e2\u0219nov, Bra\u0219ov County","Category":"1"}]}
```

So it replaces â with \u00e2, can I do that from Android?

EDIT: To clarify, I need a way of sending accented characters to my database via php. If I send them as they are (ie. â) then the json_decode fails.

I have done

> utf8_encode

in php and `new String (oldstring.getBytes(),"UTF-8")` in android and it didn't help.

EDIT: It works now, I don't know why, afaik I've made no changes.

Answer (score 2):

This could be due to Android not accepting those specific characters and it replaces it with the associated code.

Only some versions of Android will accept all accented Characters.

Please have a look at the following link : 
http://forums.omgpop.com/forum-feedback/3519-android-app-cannot-add-accented-characters.html

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4229/is-it-possible-to-type-accented-letters-using-the-galaxy-s-english-keyboard

Comment: The server sends \u00e2 android converts it from that to â (using HTML.fromHTML), and when I type â android sends â. That's the problem, I need to send \u00e2. I tried using HTML.toHTML but it didn't change the accented characters and just put tags in the text.

Comment: @raybritton: Why do you need to? Isn't that correct json if it's UTF-8 encoded? (Just asking to pin it down, probably you can by telling the android json component which encoding to use)

Comment: Not sure if this well help, but you may be able to debug what you're sending/receiving is through this link: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e2/index.htm

FYI that took me ages to find :P

Comment: @raybritton I agree, it probably would work if it was UTF-8 encoded. http://php.net/utf8_encode just fyi

Comment: @hakre, because phps json_decode can't read the accented characters for some reason.

Comment: Okay, I see two solutions: You make `cmd.getJSON().toString()` to return valid JSON. Or you filter the input prior to decode it in PHP. I think the first would be the right solution, however I'm not fluent with Android development, but probably you can dig something from the specs.

Comment: @hakre, that is valid JSON afaik, and other peoples tools agree.
getJSON() returns JSONObject if the json wasn't valid, it would throw a JSONException.

Comment: Then the PHP `json_decode` function is broken as it's unable to process valid json? I doubt (but better strictly check, create a testcase and if broken please report to bugs.php.net). Probably you first need to convert the json string to UTF-8 then PHP's `json_decode` can deal with it (it only accepts UTF-8 encoded strings). Maybe http://php.net/json_decode has some hints about this (and there are some flags with that function, not always documented).

Comment: @hakre it's unlikely that JSONObject or json_decode are broken, the string may not be UTF-8 encoded (but I'm pretty sure it is), I may be sending it wrong, although the strings match on android and on the server.

Comment: @raybritton: I put your *Example* json string as UTF-8 into PHP code and PHP's `json_decode` has no problem to handle it: http://codepad.viper-7.com/AnOfWU - I first thought this might be your problem.